# Storage Access API, first person interaction

Tags: cookies, iframe, safari, storage-access-api

I have website *a.com*, that has an iframe loading *b.com* in it. In order for the browser to save cookies from b.com in Safari, I have to access the Storage Access API. This requires user interaction with the content in the iframe. The problem is that user gestures with *b.com* are not being detected, and `requestStorageAccess()` is automatically being rejected. When I open *b.com* in a separate tab and interact with it, and then come back to *a.com*, requestStorageAccess() successfully makes the request when processing a user gesture.

I would like to understand why the user interacting with b.com *within* the iframe, without going to b.com itself, is insufficient.

The error I get is:

`[ITP] Cannot grant storage access to 'b.com' since its cookies are blocked in third-party contexts and it has not received user interaction as first-party.`

Storage Access API: https://webkit.org/blog/8124/introducing-storage-access-api/
requestStorageAccess(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/requestStorageAccess

Comment: In context of Safari/Firefox first party means that the opened webpage is first party and all iframes are third party. I assume this means you open the page click something and then you will be granted access to storage api.